# pointer and type cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

True or false:
The following assignment is valid:

```
#define GIMME *(unsigned int**) 0x3000 
unsigned short d = 42; 
GIMME = &d;
```

This is false, though I'm unable to understand why. I've recently shifted form Java to C so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define "valid"? It seems correct if the lines are in a function definition. The integer `0x3000` will be converted to a pointer in implementation-defined manner and `unsigned short` and `unsigned int` may have the same alignment requirement.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: This isn't the code you're looking for. Get a good C book instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT: but `unsigned short *` and `unsigned int *` are different types, and you can't assign one to the other without an explicit cast.  Either the cast in `GIMME` needs to be `(unsigned short **)`, or `&d` needs to be cast to `unsigned int *`.

Comment: @JohnBode This code [compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SirzQ77vSEF5Yh9l) (with warnings). Are you sure you are not confused with C++?

Comment: Doesn't the code break the strict aliasing rule? No `void`- or `char`-pointers around. @MikeCAT

Comment: @alk I guess no because there are no dereferencing in the code except for dereferencing the pointer converted from `0x3000`.

Comment: So, is there no such thing as implicit type casting in C? Or do pointers have to have the same type or be cast explicitly?

Comment: @stella97 There is absolutely no need to ever cast a pointer at your skill level. If you do you're doing something wrong.

Comment: To state this on the wording: There is no explicit/implicit casting, as "casting" is implicitly explicit. The other thing is called "implicit conversion": `char c = 'a'; int i = c; /* implicit conversion from char to int here */`

Comment: @2501: The Berkley Socket API *requires* casting pointers (addresses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is attempting 2 questionable things:

1. Assigning data to *some* location (3000) that is not known to be valid.

   ```
   *(unsigned int**) 0x3000  = &d;
   ```
2. Attempting to assign incompatible types.  Alignment may fail as `unsigned short` can be narrower than `unsigned int`.  IOWs, the 2 types *may* have different minimum alignment requirements.

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. C11 §6.3.2.3 7

```
    // similar simplified example
    unsigned short d = 42; 
    unsigned int* gimme;
    gimme = &d;  // warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```